# Calculation of the Standardized Precipitation-Evapotranspiration Index (SPEI) only returns NA values

Tags: r

I tried to calculate a SPEI (aggregation over two months) for my 225 sites but spei only returns NA's. What is wrong with my dataset?

I have a data frame with 225 columns; each containing the water balance for a certain site. The rows (48) represent the different months starting in June 2013 up to May 2016.

This is how the first four rows of the first two columns look like:

```
   BE_HI_T1_P1 BE_HI_T1_P2
1      -46.67      -46.82
2      -92.98      -93.44
3      -73.53      -74.78
4       22.13       20.53
```

I work with a data frame with only numerical values and no NA's:

```
'data.frame':   48 obs. of  225 variables:
 $ BE_HI_T1_P1: num  -46.7 -93 -73.5 22.1 72.4 ...
 $ BE_HI_T1_P2: num  -46.8 -93.4 -74.8 20.5 70.6 ...
 $ BE_HI_T1_P3: num  -47.2 -95.2 -80.4 12.9 61.7 ...
 $ BE_HI_T1_P4: num  -45.3 -87.5 -58.6 40.4 91.4 ...
 $ BE_HI_T1_P5: num  -47 -94 -76.4 33.6 84.7 ...
 $ BE_HI_T2_P1: num  3.51 -3.39 10.13 70.57 90.88 ...
 $ BE_HI_T2_P2: num  7.16 2.12 15.19 74.31 94.39 ...
 $ BE_HI_T2_P3: num  -6.95 -20.02 -6.14 58.14 79.49 ...
 $ BE_HI_T2_P4: num  22 23.2 33.2 86.5 106.5 ...
 $ BE_HI_T2_P5: num  16.1 15 26.6 78 97.9 ...
 $ BE_HI_T3_P1: num  56.49 23.34 -6.19 28.52 33.55 ...
 $ BE_HI_T3_P2: num  43.03 6.38 -20.98 18.9 28.05 ...
 $ BE_HI_T3_P3: num  75.3 48.5 19.9 47.3 45.4 ...
 $ BE_HI_T3_P4: num  56.79 23.73 -5.83 28.76 33.7 ...
 $ BE_HI_T3_P5: num  65.9 35.5 5.7 -22.5 14.2 ...
 $ BE_LO_T1_P1: num  -9.76 -62.88 -105.31 -43.44 38.4 ...
 $ BE_LO_T1_P2: num  -19.2 -70.4 -108.1 -43.8 37.2 ...
 $ BE_LO_T1_P3: num  13.8 -42 -96.7 -42 42.3 ...
 $ BE_LO_T1_P4: num  -12.4 -65.1 -106.2 -43.6 38 ...
 $ BE_LO_T1_P5: num  -64.72 -91.92 -86.62 4.73 96.85 ...
 $ BE_LO_T2_P1: num  -64.34 -90.78 -83.66 8.22 100.42 ...
 $ BE_LO_T2_P2: num  -65.23 -94.14 -93.6 -5.28 86.06 ...
 $ BE_LO_T2_P3: num  -63.3 -86.6 -72.3 22.5 114.1 ...
 $ BE_LO_T2_P4: num  -63.5 -88.2 -76.9 16.8 108.8 ...
 $ BE_LO_T2_P5: num  -14.86 -0.27 0.85 55.43 114.2 ...
 $ BE_LO_T3_P1: num  -25.8 -18.2 -17.1 42.5 103.2 ...
 $ BE_LO_T3_P2: num  3.2 26.4 24.4 73.5 130.5 ...
 $ BE_LO_T3_P3: num  -15.68 -1.56 -0.39 55.72 114.45 ...
 $ BE_LO_T3_P4: num  -7.64 10.81 11.2 64.45 122.12 ...
 $ BE_LO_T3_P5: num  37.16 26.47 -16.55 9.96 57.21 ...
 $ BE_ME_T1_P1: num  38.41 12.88 -25.17 9.14 23.64 ...
 ....
```

This is the code I try to run:

```
library(SPEI)
DataSPEI <- spei(ts(DataWaterBalance,freq=12,start=c(2013,6)),2)
```

My results look like this:

```
         BE_HI_T1_P1 BE_HI_T1_P2 
Jun 2013          NA          NA                  
Jul 2013          NA          NA                
Aug 2013          NA          NA                 
Sep 2013          NA          NA 

 > str(DataSPEI)
List of 8
 $ call        : language spei(data = ts(DataWaterBalance, freq = 12, start = c(2013, 6)), scale = 2)
 $ fitted      : Time-Series [1:48, 1:225] from 2013 to 2017: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr    [1:225] "BE_HI_T1_P1" "BE_HI_T1_P2" "BE_HI_T1_P3" "BE_HI_T1_P4" ...
 $ coefficients: logi [1:3, 1:225, 1:12] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 3
  .. ..$ par: chr [1:3] "xi" "alpha" "kappa"
  .. ..$    : chr [1:225] "BE_HI_T1_P1" "BE_HI_T1_P2" "BE_HI_T1_P3" "BE_HI_T1_P4" ...
  .. ..$    : NULL
 $ scale       : num 2
 $ kernel      :List of 3
  ..$ type  : chr "rectangular"
  ..$ shift : num 0
  ..$ values: num [1:2] 0.5 0.5
 $ distribution: chr "log-Logistic"
 $ fit         : chr "ub-pwm"
 $ na.action   : logi FALSE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "spei"
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Search for `NA`s with `sapply(my_df, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))`.

Comment: Hi, There are no NA's in my original dataset (DataWaterBalance)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is an na.rm argument that should be passed, if you have other NA's it will impact this. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/SPEI/SPEI.pdf

Comment: Hi, I already tried to add na.rm = TRUE but it doesn't change anything. There are no NA's in my DataWaterBalance data frame